# How to call a CMS page in another CMS page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms

I have two CMS pages in magento 2 . I want to call one cms page to another cms page.

anyone can help me.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, for these types of task we use static block and call static block in other cms pages

Comment: actually i have used layout xml in another cms. so i can not use block  instead of pages

Answer (score 0):

Add following xml in **Design -> Layout Update XML**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Page" name="another_cms_page" after="cms_page">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="page_id" xsi:type="number">7</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

[image]

Now create **app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Page.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Block;

use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Page extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
     */
    private $filterProvider;

    /**
     * @var PageRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $pageRepository;

    /**
     * Page constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
     * @param PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare global layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $pageId = $this->getPageId();
        $cmsPage = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);
        $this->setPage($cmsPage);
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare HTML content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($this->getPage()->getContent());
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Cms\Model\Page::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getPage()->getId()];
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Add following code inside cms block content:

```
{{block class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Page" page_id="7"}}
```

Comment: I have banner and some content in that page i want to call another cms page after banner and content

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: my both pages are cms page, so what should i write instead of "SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Page"

Comment: its not working for me bro